# JFrame low performance

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage, joptionpane, awtrobot

`JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog` takes inputs slowly. There is a half a second gap between the user key action to reflect to text box.

Also the application (.jar file) takes more memory, approx. 75mb (Application uses JNA Windows low level Keyhook events).

How can I optimize!

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,25,1366,744));
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.toFront();
frame.requestFocus();
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter file name");
frame.dispose();
String fileName= dovalidateFile(name);
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG", ".png");
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File (fileName));
int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if ( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )
{
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    file = validateFile(file);
    System.out.println(file);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", file);
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on the swing Event Dispach Thread?

Comment: No, it is not. It's inside the switch statement. Whenever the PrtSc is pressed from the keyboard, this code runs.

Comment: `How can I optimize!` This should probably be posted on CodeReview hence you're looking for optimization. Don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage bi=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,25,1366,744));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.toFront();
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter file name");
        frame.dispose();
        String fileName= dovalidateFile(name);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG", ".png");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File (fileName));
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if ( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )
        {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            final File validatedFile = validateFile(file);
            System.out.println(file);
            try{
                ImageIO.write(bi, "png", validatedFile);
            }catch(Excepion e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: @Dmitry. Thanks for your answer. the keyword final gives an error. `file = validateFile(file);` The method validateFile validates the file

Comment: fixed - use `validatedFile` instead of `file`

Comment: Thank you. But the input still loads slow to the input box. Should I go for any alternate text box?

Comment: fixed. it's possibly because of `robot.createScreenCapture` method. Just wrap all stuf with `new Thread()`.

Comment: @TT I was not aware of it. Thanks for educating